# NiFi PutDatabaseRecord to Postgres database : Performance improvement in loading data into Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi

We are trying to load data to postgres from oracle using nifi.
we are using PutDatabaseRecord to load data (which is in avro format).
we are using ExecuteSQL to extract data which is very fast but we can see that,
even though we are using 150+ threads for PutDatabaseRecord, it is maintaining an average of 1GB data writes for 5mins .
If suppose we are having 3 PutDatabaseRecord processors (i.e., let suppose for each table one processor) and each processor is of 50 threads, still it is maintaining an average of 1Gb for 5 mins (i.e., 250mb for 1 processor, 350 for 2nd processor and 400 for 3 processor. Or some other combinations but it is still 1Gb overall).

[image: example]

We are really, not sure if it is from postgres database end which is limiting write size or it's from nifi end.

Need help if we need to change NiFi properties or to change some settings in postgres, which will help the data loading performance.

One observation is that, data extraction from Oracle is very fast and we are able to see the Nifi queues are filling very quickly and waiting to be processed by PutDatabaseRecord process.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single NiFi instance, there will be limit on how much data you can push through regardless of the number of threads (once the number of threads reaches the number of cores on your machine). To increase throughput, you could set up a 3-5 node NiFi cluster and run the PutDatabaseRecord processors in parallel, then you should see 3-5 GB throughput to Postgres (as long as PG can handle that)